# Use of Images, is there a stackexchange policy

Tags: discussion, images, copyright

I am amazed at the image used in [Can I fly with a gold bar?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50882/can-i-fly-with-a-gold-bar) this is apparently not the OP's image (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_as_an_investment) and no, the OP did not say that and practically it adds nothing to the content of the question.  I am only thinking if use of such images ok in this site and if anyone knows, stackexchange in general.  I am sure this is a common question and may have been discussed earlier, can I get anyone to guide me to the right place?

Comment: The image in that question is listed under a public domain license, so it's not even necessary to specify the author.

Comment: I got that image from Wikipedia and their license does not conflict with SE license

Comment: For reference: here's a [link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gold_bullion_2.jpg) to wiki commons with the image and the relevant licence. It says indeed "I grant anyone the right to use this work for any purpose, without any conditions, unless such conditions are required by law.".

Comment: Also see: [Usage of photos and maps?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/593/108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SE users should always make sure that the content they post is not infringing copyright, and must respect the license of the content they post. This is explained in [the Terms and Conditions of SE under 3) Subscriber Content](http://stackexchange.com/legal):

> #### 3. Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You. Subscriber warrants, represents and agrees Subscriber has the right to grant Stack Exchange and the Network the rights set forth above. **Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party,** (b) reveals any trade secret, unless Subscriber owns the trade secret or has the owner’s permission to post it, (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another, (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive, threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any law or right of any third party, (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information, or (f) remains posted after Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence. Stack Exchange reserves the right to remove any Subscriber Content from the Network, re-post to the Network any Subscriber Content removed by any Subscriber or former Subscriber, suspend or terminate Subscriber’s right to use the Services at any time, or pursue any other remedy or relief available to Stack Exchange and/or the Network under equity or law, for any reason (including, but not limited to, upon receipt of claims or allegations from third parties or authorities relating to such Subscriber Content or if Stack Exchange is concerned that Subscriber may have breached the immediately preceding sentence), or for no reason at all.